# How to uninstall a license key

Tags: windows-8, license

I bought Windows 8 Professional, updated to it from my Win 7 Pro and it's great. All in all, I wanna keep using Windows 8, but something went wrong with my Visual Studio 2012 Professional installation. Now [there is no way I can install the target version for .NET 4.0](https://superuser.com/questions/494553/net-framework-4-0-targeting-pack-does-not-show-in-visual-studio), and I really need this to comply with old projects without affecting other developers.

I do have an official license key, bought when installing Windows 8, so my question is, now that I need to format, then reinstall Win 7 Pro, then reupgrade to Win 8 Pro, **how do I make sure my next activation is successful?**

In other words, how can I [not change](https://superuser.com/questions/496081/how-can-i-change-the-license-key-on-windows-8), but **remove my license** so I can use it again when everything is fresh and updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use your license on a clean install, you need to backup and restore your activation files.

- Backup the `store` folder located here: `%WinDir%\System32\spp\store\`.

  - Make sure that your backup folder contains the three files: `data.dat`, `tokens.dat`, and `cache\cache.dat`.
- To uninstall a key, right click on the Start corner > Command Prompt (Admin) > Yes > Type:

  ```
  slmgr -upk
  ```

  - Actually, there is no need to uninstall your key before clean install. You can just skip this step. After you format, your Windows 8 installation will be removed anyway.
  - However, in the clean installation, if you had used a default install key, you should uninstall that key.
- After you clean install Windows 8, boot into safe mode > Right click on the Start corner > Command Prompt (Admin) > Yes > Type:

  ```
  net stop sppsvc
  ```
- Restore the backed up `store` folder to its location in `%WinDir%\System32\spp\`.
- Restart.

It is a good idea to make a backup of your OS drive before performing these steps and a clean install.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can download the ISO file for Win8 PRO and re-install Windows 8 booting from that ISO (dvd or usb) using the serial given during the update process.

Comment: ok, but this does not answer my original question: How to uninstall the license.

Comment: you can't. Windows activate that serial on your pc and vinculate it on the hardware you're using

Comment: @balexandre - You wipe the hdd.  This would "uninstall" the license and allow you to use the Windows 7 license.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot uninstall a license key in a way you uninstall an application.

If you use the key only on one computer, Windows will activate.

That means you can reformat the drive, install Windows 7 Pro with its key, upgrade to Windows 8 with its key.

You can even transfer the upgrade to another computer, if it's eligible for upgrade provided you re-install Windows 7 on your current which was upgraded.

If you have a retail version of Windows 7, non-OEM, you can install it on another computer, and it will activate, although you may have to use phone-activation (since the hardware changed significantly). Then you can also upgrade it to Windows 8. Of course, this assumes you still use it *only one computer*.

Comment: I have used one license key on many computers and it never got mad at me :P.  As long as 200 people don't use your key I think OP should be ok...

Comment: @Wijagels You were lucky! ;) I had to [re-activate](http://alexyv.wordpress.com/2011/08/17/activate-windows-7/) my Windows 7 installation after I had changed motherboard. And the phone robot asked me on _how many computers_ I installed this copy of Windows.